# Application vs middleware development in Android

Tags: android, middleware

I have 1 year and 6 months of experience on  Android. All of my experience has been into application development. Recently I have got offers from two companies. One is offering me a profile to work on application layer and other is offering a profile on Android middleware. Can you guide me which would be better.Is middleware development better than application layer development from the career perspective in terms of money and other opportunities.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This should be asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Agree, still i posted an answer before seeing this comment...

Answer (score 8):

Both has its own pros and cons, thats for sure. One thing to emphasize is though middleware is into server-side programming. Client side is nice and cool at the moment, but five years from now, i am sure Android will have totally different looks, different tooling, different UX paradigms, different API's. So the skillset you develop by doing client work will need a magnitude more effort to update, and new developers just starting will catch your experience level very quickly in such dynamic environment. On the server side, the concepts of design patterns, scalability principles and other stuff will help you develop your expertise in a much stronger way against the technology changes and new developers. Don't get me wrong, server side is not easier, it gets a similar amount of effort, but the erosion is smaller compared to client side techs. What you learn and add to your arsenal will not be useless in a short time. I would go for the server side if you are into architecture and alike. You can still keep doing stuff on the client platforms...

(An architect/developer with around ten years of experience on both sides of the story)

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt help lithium.Can you tell me as to who will earn more a five year application layer guy or a  middleware guy

Comment: that depends...
there is no such comparison, but the last 1-2 years were and probably the next 3-5 years will be very hot for the frontend developers, if you are good at what you do and if you can find a good matching company to work for. On the other hand, system architects, server programmers are almost always in big demand... I believe server guys will be able to find "better paying jobs" or "jobs with better conditions".

Comment: thansk a lot for your reviews lithium

Comment: I generally agree, though developing UI on different frameworks leaves a sediment of patterns and structures you would reuse independently of tools evolution.